# React component (textarea) won't re-render with new style from updated state

Tags: reactjs, textarea, state, styled-components

The two text areas are only slightly different, and I can't understand why the second won't work .

[Here's the Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexXodov/pen/rwGBQY?editors=0010).

```
const StyledTextarea = styled.textarea`
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  min-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 7px;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  resize: none;
  width: 500px;
`;

const Label = styled.span`
  color: ${props => props.green ? '#00BB00' : 'red'};
  font-size: 1.5em;
`;

const App = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Label green>✅ Textarea1 - Working </Label>
      <Textarea1 />
      <Label>❌ Textarea2 - Not working </Label>
      <Textarea2 />
    </div>
  )
}

class Textarea1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda voluptas deleniti at, molestias in amet dolore voluptatem atque, modi minus ipsam dignissimos...',
          scrollHeight: 0,
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
      const t = e.target;
      t.style.height = 'auto';
      t.style.height = `${t.scrollHeight}px`;
      this.setState({value: t.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledTextarea
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

class Textarea2 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda voluptas deleniti at, molestias in amet dolore voluptatem atque, modi minus ipsam dignissimos...',
          scrollHeight: 0,
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
      const bugger = e.target;
       console.log('style.height before it is set to auto: ', bugger.style.height)
      bugger.style.height = 'auto';
       console.log('style.height after it is set to auto (obviously): ', bugger.style.height)
       console.log('.scroll height: ', bugger.scrollHeight);
      this.setState({
        scrollHeight: bugger.scrollHeight,
        value: bugger.value
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledTextarea
              style={{height: `${this.state.scrollHeight}px`}}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Both use a similar way of keeping their height in sync with the height of the content. However, the second, which I thought should re-render with the new `style.height` (coming from the updated state), doesn't apply the new style. Watch the console for the values in question - style.height stays 'auto' even after the assignment of the new value .
It works though if you only press Enter and Backspace .

What is it I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky problem more related to your usage of the [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) library with React than your React code itself. In the render of your `Textarea1` you are creating a `StyledTextarea` with a style prop passed in. Unfortunately this prop is ignored by components created with styled-components.

When using styled-components with react you are supposed to pull your props out and apply them to your css, as shown in [this code-pen](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/qmZVWm):

```
const styled = styled.default;

const Button = styled.button`
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  height: ${props => props.small ? 40 : 60}px;
  width: ${props => props.small ? 60 : 120}px;
`;

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button small>Click Me</Button>
        <Button large>Click Me</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

To fix your problem you will have to pull your style.height prop out in your `StyledTextArea` and reset your height to `''` at the end of Textarea2.onChange. Here is your code with these changes. Note that this breaks the resizing done in Textarea1:

```
const styled = styled.default;

const StyledTextarea = styled.textarea`
  display: block;
  font-family: PT Sans;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  min-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 7px;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  resize: none;
  width: 500px;
  // one update here
  height: ${props => (props.style && props.style.height) ? props.style.height + 'px' : '0px'};
`;

const Label = styled.span`
  color: ${props => props.green ? '#00BB00' : 'red'};
  font-size: 1.5em;
`;

const App = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Label green>✅ Textarea1 - Working </Label>
      <Textarea1 />
      <Label>❌ Textarea2 - Not working </Label>
      <Textarea2 />
    </div>
  )
}

class Textarea1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda voluptas deleniti at, molestias in amet dolore voluptatem atque, modi minus ipsam dignissimos...',
          scrollHeight: 0,
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
      const t = e.target;
      t.style.height = 'auto';
      t.style.height = `${t.scrollHeight}px`;
      this.setState({value: t.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledTextarea
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

class Textarea2 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda voluptas deleniti at, molestias in amet dolore voluptatem atque, modi minus ipsam dignissimos...',
          scrollHeight: 0,
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
      const bugger = e.target;
       console.log('style.height before it is set to auto: ', bugger.style.height)
      bugger.style.height = 'auto';
       console.log('style.height after it is set to auto (obviously): ', bugger.style.height)
       console.log('.scroll height: ', bugger.scrollHeight);
      this.setState({
        scrollHeight: bugger.scrollHeight,
        value: bugger.value
      });
      // another update here
      bugger.style.height = '';
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.scrollHeight);
        return (
            <StyledTextarea
              style={{height: this.state.scrollHeight}}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

A final note, the second approach you are using is definitely the more preferable one! Modifying your components styles via a handler as opposed to the render method is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks man, it now works! You could go with just a `height` prop and use it like this: `height: ${props => props.height && `${props.height}px`};` I've updated the codepen to include the working example. 

However, it is not completely true that `style` prop is ignored by a `styled component`. Here's a [link](https://codepen.io/AlexXodov/pen/YQrGma?editors=0010) to a simplified range slider that respects it (only works on clicks but you get the idea). It seems like a `styled component` is not guaranteed to pass `style` to the underlying DOM node, but it may. I wonder whichever is by design.

Comment: On a sidenote, do you think it's worth using `styled components`, performance and complication-wise, to manage frequently changing values, like e.g. an element's position when it's being dragged?

Comment: 1) Im glad it was helpful! 2) Yup, your improvement to just pass the height seems cleaner. good call. 3) That is odd that it sometimes works. my guess is that it may have to do with the type of dom element that is generated? I noticed in your example here a `<div>` is created while in the original one a `<textarea>` is created.

Comment: 4) That is a good question but I don't work enough with the library to tell you and a quick search on 'styled-components performance' didn't turn anything up for me. You could try searching a bit more, looking at their source code, or see if there is a good place to ask their community.